# Android tab clicked

Tags: java, android, android-tabs

I'm trying to apply TABs to my Android layout. How could I identify which tab was clicked?

I have an android tab layout made this way:

```
package com.truiton.designsupporttabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);
    }
}
```

With the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Tab 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I do not know how to identify that a tab like the above example was clicked.

Comment: Be careful with repeated questions, which can be easily found on the internet.

Comment: Tanks for the feedback @RobertoPinheiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having as a principle that your code was based on the [Truiton](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/) tutorial, just follow how they identify the clicks.

```
package com.truiton.designsupporttabs;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

**This should work!**